# Chartist line graphs animation starts from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chartist.js

I'm using Chartist.js to generate line graphs, It works great, but I notice lines animation starts at the beginning in a certain height from chart bottom by default:

[image]

How can I modify my code to start lines animation from the bottom of the chart like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
function graph(month,shop,sale){
    var data = {         
      labels: month,          
      series: [sale,shop]
    };

    var options = {
      fullWidth:true,
      height: 380, 
      showPoint: true,
      low: 0,
      showArea: true,
      lineSmooth: false,
      plugins: [
          Chartist.plugins.legend({
              legendNames: ['Sale', 'Shop'],
          })
      ]
    };

   var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);

    chart.on('draw', function(data) {
      if(data.type === 'point') {
        var circle = new Chartist.Svg('circle', {
          cx: [data.x], cy:[data.y], r:[5],
        }, 'ct-circle');
        data.element.replace(circle);
      }
    });

    chart.on('draw', function(data) {
      if(data.type === 'line' || data.type === 'area') {
        data.element.animate({
          d: {
            begin: 1000 * data.index,
            dur: 1000,
            from: data.path.clone().scale(1, 0).translate(0, data.chartRect.height()).stringify(),
            to: data.path.clone().stringify(),
            easing: Chartist.Svg.Easing.easeOutQuint
          }
        });
      }
    });      
}

var data = {         
   labels: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio']
};

var options = {
  fullWidth:true,
  height: 380
};

new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "myfile.php",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp)
      {
        var month = resp[0];
        var shop = resp[1];
        var sale = resp[2];  

        graph(month,shop,sale);
      }
  });
});
```

I would like some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the elements with the google developer tools, you will find out that the class "ct-series ct-series-b" from the chart, has an specific height that it doesn't go all the way down. If you then change in the animation when the chart is drawing to something like:

```
from: data.path.clone().scale(1, 0).translate(0, data.chartRect.height() + 15).stringify(),
```

The line will start from the height of the ct-series-b + 15px all the way up to the circle points.

Hope it helps, Leo.